# imagick - Identify transparent areas of an image and write to a file - can this be done away from the command line?

Tags: php, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a imagemagick convert command which identifies the non transparent regions of a PNG and writes them to a file.

```
convert mask.png -alpha extract -negate -define connected-components:verbose=true -define connected-components:area-threshold=100  -connected-components 8 -auto-level  result.png > data2.cc
```

The output looks like this:

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 1748x2480+0+0 872.2,1240.4 2983832 gray(255)
  1: 814x1664+470+406 876.5,1237.5 1351208 gray(0)
```

Now I am using Laravel and I would like to be able to run this command at the point a file is uploaded - is that possible using the [ImageMagick functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)?

I've looked through the documentation for key words like extract and components and they are not listed - so either the equivalent functions do not exist or have a different naming convention?

I would really like to avoid using exec() - but any guidence would be really appreciated, even if it is confirming the technical term for what I am trying to achieve which might aid my search.

[My line of research was inspired by this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244191/imagemagick-detect-coordinates-of-transparent-areas) and then [this is where I found the command to write to the file.](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=30973)

Comment: If you wish to execute command on file when uploaded, write small batch which will check upload directory for new file, execute the extract, save it in txt file, move the original file to another location or delete it, etc. Add the batch/script to a cron and execute the cron every few sec. In php just display the output of the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion from Grzegorz Sapijaszko here is the bash script I wrote to take the PNG's and pass them through the command to analyze the elements within the image.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd public/builder/printposition/raw/mask/new/;
for filename in *.png; do
        convert $filename -alpha extract -negate -define connected-components:verbose=true -define connected-components:area-threshold=100 -connected-components 8 -auto-level  result.png > ../parsed/$filename.cc;
        rm result.png;
        mv $filename ../parsed/$filename;
done
```

This moves to the directory on line 2, loops through any PNG files and runs the command against it, storing the result in a .cc file (of the same name) in a 2nd location and and moving the PNG with it so it doesn't get processed a second time.

The command generates a result.png file but I simply remove this on line 5.

Hopefully this might prove useful for someone else.